# How does manually assigning tableView.rowheight affect subviews of the given Table View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom view for displaying application status messages that I slide over my table view as needed. This worked fine until I started customizing my table view cells.

When I manually assign a row height to my table view cells in *initWithSTyle*...

`self.TableView.rowHeight = 64.0;`

...the custom view doesn't show up anymore.

I replaced the code above with a delegate method...

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

{

```
return 64.0;
```

}

...and now the custom view works as before.

Comment: Where do you call `self.TableView.rowHeight = 64.0;` ?

Comment: Good question...I think I did it in initWithStyle. Would that be an issue? (Sorry, I moved on from the code after I got it working with heightForRowAtIndexPath.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `rowHeight` in the view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 64.0f;
}
```

I think `initWithStyle` is too early to set the height. Eitherway, since your height is constant, it's still more efficient to set the height once (in `viewDidLoad`) than set it every time for each cell created (in `initWithStyle` or `heightForRowAtIndexPath`).

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I was indeed looking for a non-dynamic place to set the cell's row height.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a custom cell class inheriting `UITableVIewCell` , if yes , then the height of customcell is different than the height of default cell.So you need to change the height of row to match your customcell;s in order for it to desplay correctly,Else cellswill overlap.

To Dynamically set height accoring to your customcell:-

```
YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return [cell.frame.size.height];
```

Comment: Thanks. I did create a custom table view cell class, but they are displaying properly.  The issue was that a subview of the Table View stopped appearing. This issue went away when I started using the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. But I'm still curious as to what caused it to begin with.

Comment: You might have added many controls to customcells which changes the height of your customcell but by default height set a lot lower and hence if uyou do not set height accordingly in cellforrowatindexpath , they will overlap and some won't show

Answer (score 0):

```
    maintableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    maintableView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    maintableView.rowHeight = 100.0;
    maintableView.delegate=self;
    maintableView.dataSource=self;
```

It is working in my Xcode. Try like it. I think it will work.